# Resize Header onscroll React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to basically rewrite this codepen in react. 
 https://codepen.io/lili2311/pen/dJjuL

```
function resizeHeaderOnScroll() {
 const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || 
 document.documentElement.scrollTop,
 shrinkOn = 200,
 headerEl = document.getElementById('js-header');

if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
   headerEl.classList.add("smaller");
   } else {
    headerEl.classList.remove("smaller");
   }
 }

window.addEventListener('scroll', resizeHeaderOnScroll);
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple implementation would include

1. adding the scroll event listener to componentDidmount,
2. changing class to className,
3. adding html to render()
4. including the css

I have created the same for you in [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrz0595p07)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my try. Not sure if it going to work properly or not but It will give you a general idea how to build it in react.

```js
//Create a navbar component
class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    //In the state you can keep track of the class you want to add to the element
    this.state = {
      class: "" //For now its empty or you can give it a default class.
    }
  }

  //use the lifecycle methods to trigger the getWindowHeight method.

  componentDidMount(){
     () => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.getWindowHeight);
     }
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.getWindowHeight);
    }
  }

  //then create the method
  getWindowHeight = () {

    const distanceY = window.pageYOffset ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop
    const shrinkOn = "200px";

    //Now In the condition change the state to smaller so if the condition is true it will change to smaller otherwise to default state
    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
      this.setState({
        class: "smaller"
      })
    }
  }
  
render() {
  return (
    //Now in the element you can add the state to the class as well as add event to the onScroll
    <navbar className={this.state.class} >
    </navbar >
  )
}
```